# 'Open in browser' redirects me back to the app

Tags: bug, android-app

*I'm using the SE app on an Android phone (Galaxy S5 OS 6.0).*

When I try the option to view a question in a browser, it simply opens the same question in the app. It doesn't even try opening the browser.

**Is this a common issue, or am I the only one experiencing it?**

Things I've tried:

- clearing defaults for the SE app,
- clearing defaults for my browsers,
- clearing data for the SE app,
- restarting my phone

Here's the option I'm talking about:

[image: Here's the option I'm talking about]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this in Marshmallow:

- "Settings"
- "Application Manager"
- "Stack Exchange"
- "Set as Default"
- "Go to supported URLs"
- Set to "Always ask", or set the app that you want to handle links.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks.